# Meta chatroom back from the dead!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I regularly visit the Mathematics Educators chat rooms ([ME](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13591/mathematics-educators) and [Innumeracy](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34405/innumeracy)) and now I just saw a third chat room ([Mathematics Educators Meta](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19867/mathematics-educators-meta)) that wasn't there before.  It was created on December 30, 2014 and it seems that the last activity there was 423 days ago.

> Why did this chatroom suddenly appear out of nowhere?

Comment: "Meta chatroom back from the dead! 2" https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/530/77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appeared due to my [request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277349/why-can-meta-sites-be-parents-of-chatrooms#comment898526_277355) on meta.SE.

That chatroom always existed, but didn't appear although it should have. Now it does.