# Disappearing Meta chatroom

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I regularly visit the [Mathematics Educators chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=matheducators.stackexchange.com) and I used to see three.  But starting last March 16, 2017, the [Mathematics Educators Meta chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19867/mathematics-educators-meta) disappeared from the list.  (Clicking the "[Show frozen/deleted rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=matheducators.stackexchange.com)" button doesn't reveal it.)  The room is still active and posts there can be seen and made.

Why did this room disappear from the list?

Comment: No idea. I'll ask a user on math.se which is an expert on chat-features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that; this was fallout from the https switchover; the chat rooms hadn't had their individual hosts updated to reflect the "meta.*.stackexchange.com" => "*.meta.stackexchange.com" switch - so it was applying the wrong filter. I've now fixed this. Thanks for reporting it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps somebody will be able to expand on this, but at least I can tell you how to find the "missing" chat room.

If I display rooms [associated with Math Educators](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=matheducators.stackexchange.com), currently I see two rooms. And I see one additional room [associated with Meta Math Educators](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com). I can only get the later link by manually changing url. (If I click on list of sites in chat, I am not able to find Meta Math Educators.) [This room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19867/mathematics-educators-meta) is the only room displayed in the latter list and the first two rooms are [this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13591/mathematics-educators) and [this one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/34405/innumeracy).

If you have all three rooms among your favorite rooms (as I do) and choose to [display favorite rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=favorite), you should see all three (alongside other rooms you favorited).

---

The rooms for main and meta used to be displayed separately. This changed in March 2016, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277349/why-can-meta-sites-be-parents-of-chatrooms/277355#277355).

So my guess this is a bug related to recent changes of urls for per site metas. (You probably noticed that the url for meta changed from `meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com` to `matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com`.)

If my guess is correct, this should probably be reported as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). (Although having such "hidden" room might have some advantages.)

Comment: Thanks.  I've reposted my question on the main meta as you suggested: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292773/disappearing-meta-chatroom